# How to not run a test if the alert is closed

Tags: groovy, soapui

Below is have a piece of code that handle an alert which contains a drop down:

**SoapUI Project Setup Script**

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.*
def alert = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport
def urls = []

project.properties.each 
{
    if (it.value.name.startsWith("BASE_URL_")) 
    {
        urls.push(it.value.name.replace("BASE_URL_", ""))
    }
}

def urlName = alert.prompt("Please select the environment URL", "Enter URL", urls)
```

What i have noticed is that when I select the x button to close the alert, it still runs the test (which will fail as I have not selected an environment. My question is that how can I write the code so that if the alert is closed (click the x button), it doesn't  run the test?

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you click on `cancel`?

Comment: So this code is in a project setup script. You select the project folder and select TestSuites and click run. if you press cancel or the x button, it will display an error prompt stating there's a missing endopint. Click ok on the alert and the first test suite runs with a failed test suite, then the same error appears again and after closing or click ok, the second suite fails and this continues until all suites fail

Comment: Not sure when you want to cancel? Obiviously it will fail as there  is no endpoint. I am afraid if you can control.

Comment: Virtually I just want to cancel whenever the x or cancel button is selected. It should be the op up displays to select environment, if you select your environment and confirm, it runs the whole test, if you select cancel, then just close the alert, don't run anything (or abort the test)

Comment: Then do not run the project. If am right, you may just want to test this script and not the test suites. Then you just try to run the Setup Script instead of running project.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142267/room-for-rao-and-bruceybandit

Comment: can you check the solution and see if that is what you are after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, user don't cancel the project execution.

But there is layer that you wrote on top of it before the execution of the project which will actually selects the domain address in the prompt and then cancel as user do not wish to run the project.

Right now, the script you wrote is not doing any condition check. In order to achieve what you are looking for is to have the condition to know if user has clicked on Ok or otherwise do not execute the test suites.

Here is the modified Project level `Setup Script`:

```
import static com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport.prompt
def urls = []
def prefix = 'BASE_URL_'
project.properties.each {
    if (it.value.name.startsWith(prefix)) {
        urls.push(it.value.name.replace(prefix, ""))
    }
}

def suffix = prompt("Please select the environment URL", "Enter URL", urls)
if (suffix) {
    log.info 'received user input'
    def propertyName = prefix+suffix
    def domainAddress = project.getPropertyValue(propertyName)
    log.info "Selected environment : ${propertyName} - ${domainAddress}"    
} else {
    log.warn 'haven\'t received user input'
    log.warn 'No base URL is selected or cancelled, try again'
    assert false
}
```